# What's an intelligent/sophisticated way to say "changing from negative to positive"

Tags: single-word-requests

i am currently working on a new website for posting daily articles and guides on gaining full control of your mentality.

What i am inquiring for, is a sophisticated but brief way of saying "to change from something from negative to positive.

example: 
to change negative thoughts to a positive perspective
to be pessimistic minded but to make progression towards becoming optimistic

Thank you.

Comment: But first, note that in English, the first person singular pronoun is always capitalized.

Comment: A series of Christian booklets [co-]authored by evangelist Reinhard Bonnke was (and still is) entitled 'From Minus to Plus'. Some might not think that title catchy, but perhaps they ought to tread warily; I was at a lecture where he explained Who'd told him to publish and distribute the booklets.

Answer (score 1):

**Reversal of Polarity**

See the [Merriam-Webb entry for polarity](https://www.merriam-.com/dictionary/polarity). This would seem an objective description. Or, perhaps if you must include “positive”

**Restoration of Positive Polarity**

Comment: I get the impression OP wanted something catchier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, As you well know, once a question is posted on SE it exists in itself for the list, regardless of the OP. But yes, and that’s why I answered as I did. For goodness sake, upvote my sane answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common phrase used for the subject matter of your website, is **transformation of mindset**, or more shortly, **mindset transformation.**

A few examples courtesy of Google (emphasizing that I don't necessarily endorse any of these, I'm just relaying what the search engine came up with):

[https://www.amazon.com/Mindset-Transformation-Discover-Shifting-Anything/dp/B01JZXE18E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JZXE18E)

https://alignorg.com/cultivating-successful-transformation-mindset/

https://mind-sets.com/product/mindset-transformation/